# VBA - Pass arguments from one function to another function without returning to first function

Tags: excel, vba, function, return

Any methods where I can pass variables from one function to another without returning to first function
Say:

```
Function F2(Optional endAll As Boolean = False)

Cells(R1,C1)= Evaluate(jGetFormula)

If endAll Then End


End Sub

Function f1()
jGetFormula = " = " & "A1" & "*" & 10 & "^" & 3 & "*" A2 & "/" & 148 
R1 = Selection.Row
C1 = Selection.Column
Call F2(True)

End Function
```

here function f1() creates excel formula and get corresponding row and column number of cells where =f1() entered in cell and passing these to another function and end without returning back to f1().
The function f2() takes arguments from f1() and converts the string to formula and replaces =f1() by the formula as =A1 * 10^3 * A2 / 148 in the cell where earlier =f2() was written.

Comment: Change `If endAll Then End` to `If endAll Then Exit Function`

Comment: 1.  F2 should be a `Sub` as it is not returning anything back to the caller.  2. `Sub F2(Optional endAll As Boolean = False,R1 as Long,C1 as Long,jGetFormula as String)` then call it `Call F2(True,R1,C1,JGetFormula)`

Comment: But also, if `F1` is called from the worksheet and not another Sub it will fail.

Comment: @Scott Craner I am getting compile error on this line Sub f2(Optional endAll As Boolean = False, jR1 as Long, jC1 as Long, jGetFormula as String).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function ffeeee2(jR1 As Long, jC1 As Long, jGetFormula As String, Optional endAll As Boolean = True)
        MsgBox jGetFormula
        MsgBox "function f1 entered in cell (" & jR1 & "," & jC1 & ")"
        MsgBox "This ends f2"
        If endAll Then Exit Function
    End Function

    Function ffeeee1()
        Dim jR1 As Long
        Dim jC1 As Long
        Dim jGetFormula As String
        jR1 = Selection.Row
        jC1 = Selection.Column
        jGetFormula = "Function value from f1 (row number + column number =" & jR1 + jC1 & ")"
        Call ffeeee2(jR1, jC1, jGetFormula, True)
    End Function
```